# Can / should Basic resource be used to store application settings?

Tags: hl7-fhir

At a medical device manufacturer company I work at, we are looking into consolidating our data model and APIs between products. Since I worked in the IEEE 11073 as well as HL7 Devices working group a while back, I suggested to look into HL7 FHIR for this.

We were able to map almost all concepts we are having to an existing resource or identify one where we could place an extension on.

**Goals:**

1. deployment of products in clinical environments without imposing data storage requirements or custom backend solutions = no additional data storage shall be installed and maintained within the customer's environment (e.g. additional DBMS instances or databases in a DBMS)
2. site / tenant, instance and user configuration shall be accessible through the same data model and API concept as a Patient, for example
3. interoperability of settings is not important (and can't be achieved obviously anyway) = only our products need to understand them

**Problem:**

There is no technical concept of *application configuration / settings* in FHIR.
(e.g. key-value pairs for configuring dark mode of the UI or stuff like that)

(Note: given the nature and intention of HL7, that is per-design and not a complaint!)

**Possible solutions:**

1. custom resource (which is discouraged in FHIR)
2. Basic resource and using extension(s)

**Questions:**

1. Is this a "good" (advisable) approach / design to the problem at hand?
2. Is there another concept or solution in FHIR we missed for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic is certainly an option.  A couple of other possibilities:

- Observation (often used for name/value pairs)
- Parameters (though this typically isn't persisted/searchable)

If you need complex nesting or need values other than those supported by Observation, Basic is your best bet.  It's intended for representing data that isn't really 'healthcare' data or where there's no standardization of what the data should be.  Application configuration settings would tick both boxes.

Comment: I think Observation implies it to be medical in nature, like vital signs.

I thought about Parameters as well. The non-persisted part in the spec is an issue. It can be a solution if those parameters would be dynamic in nature, meaning the server would expose internal settings as Parameter resource. That implies knowledge or some kind support on the server end.

When using COTS (commercially of the shelf) software though, Basic seems to be the best bet: servers support it, it gets persisted, server can be COTS, it doesn't interfere with deployed workflows (like Observation might)

Comment: Observations are in no way limited to 'medical'.  Observations can cover all sorts of things - location of patient valuables; pH of lake water; average visit duration for Dr. Smith's appointments; etc.